# Sharepoint 2010 server setup, possible to add it to the domain without breaking it?

Tags: migration, domain, active-directory

I have a MOSS 2010 server nicely configured but its a workgroup / stand alone setup.

I want to add the computer to the domain. Will this break the sharepoint installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not break the installation, but you may want to consider creating a new farm.  It is possible to do a migration, but given the number of service accounts that have to be reconfigured it would probably be easy to configure a new farm and re-attach the databases to bring in the content.